# Blazor lifetime scoped-service

Tags: c#, blazor, dispose

I make a spa on a blazor and when i close the View and call the Dispose method on ther service, it is not completely cleared, because the next time when i switch to the same view, constructor of this service is not called. Service declared as Scoped. I created the simple [example](https://github.com/Lapish/BlazorLifeTime).

Some explanations aboout this example. There is a main page - MainView and a second ProfileView, which has a TabControl with two tabs: FirstTabView and SecondTabView. All Views are declared as Transient services and ProfileService is declared as Scoped.

**MainView behavior**

There is a Number property, which in the constructor (MainViewModel) is infinitely incremented until the Dispose method is called. This method is made for an example of the lifetime of the Transient.

**ProfileView behavior**

After the first ui render (OnAfterRenderAsync), a fake load is called in the ProfileService.LoadProfileAsync service. After loading, it shows the time the ProfileView was created, the time the service was created (to check if it is created each time) and the time it was last updated. The first tab shows the name and the second shows connections that are constantly updated from ProfileView.

[image]

When switching between tabs (First, Second) in TabControl, property subscriptions are deleted and everything works fine, but if I leave ProfileView and navigate to MainView, then i need to release the ProfileService itself, because i don't need it. It is "freed", but the next time navigate to ProfileView page, the service's constructor is not called. And since the constructor is not called from it, then all subscriptions cannot receive their data, because in the Dispose method of this service I called OnCompleted for each field.

**Question?**

Why isn't the ProfileService constructor called when i navigate to ProfileView if i've called Dispose before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `Dispose` to delete an instance of a service.

A `Scoped` service lives for the lifetime of the SPA session.  Calling `Dispose` manually just runs whatever code you have placed in `Dispose`.  The Scoped instance of the object isn't removed until the Dependency Injection container is destroyed.  If you want to limit the life of a Scoped service to the lifetime of a component/page inherit from `OwningComponentBase`.  Search the Internet for examples of how to use it, there are several.

### Update to clarify after further (much later) comments.

In Blazor Server:

1. There is an application DI container which is created when the Web Application starts.  This contains all the Singleton Services.
2. Each Hub session - which corresponds to a SPA session - creates it's own Scoped Container.  The renderer uses this DI Container to request all injected services.  Any dependant Scoped services on the requested service are also created in this container as are any Transient services.  All Singleton services are pulled from the Application container.
3. Owning Component, or any other class that creates it's own DI container will request services from that container and any dependant services will be created in that container.  All Singleton services are pulled from the Application container.

In Blazor WASM:

1. There is only one container, created when the SPA starts.  In effect Singleton and Scoped are the same.
2. Any Owning component creates it's own container as in Server.

There is an article here - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5341118/Using-Blazors-OwningComponentBase - that describes how to handle getting services from the Hub Scoped container when using OwningComponent.

Comment: Although the `OwningComponentBase` is a good advice, the explanation of Dispose pattern is not correct. Dispose is always supposed to be called explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tested OwningComponentBase all this time and found the only option. Inherit the ProfileView from OwningComponentBase, and all children from the regular component, because if I inherit them from OwningComponentBase, then there will be different instances, but I need one. After initializing the ProfileView, I pass this service to the child components through parameters. Simple example: https://gist.github.com/Lapish/0b36bae858ead2d5b9ce6c34d4110c8b Maybe this is wrong. I don't know, but it works.

Comment: Is this not a flaw of the way Blazor is constructed. Obviously the intent of the 3 scopes from a blazor perspective are Transient = Always new, Singleton = Only 1 Instance Ever (until an f5 or page refresh occurs), Scoped = Every new Page. Does anyone else have a scenario where scoped would make sense to use that's different than every new page call?

Comment: @Lapish after thinking about this a bit, another approach you could take, which is what I'm doing (after reading this) is to add a Clear() or Dispose() call to your injected scoped interface(s). This call should clear or reset all of the stateful data of the service back to the initial state. With smaller services this is easier to accomplish. Then in the page that you were expecting this ideal behavior on, you can implement IDisposable and on Dispose call that function. If done right, the next time you access the page it should act as if it's just being created.

Comment: @misterbee I want to reset the data in my scoped service, prematurely to their default values. How and where should I use Clear() or Dispose(). That could be the solution also for me. Could you give a short example?

Comment: @Mdarende My example is being used on a page ChangeOrderDetail that makes use of scoped service changeOrderModificationSvc. I'm using this service to coordinate changes across a lot of components. When ever I leave this page I reset the data. To do this, I implement IDisposable on the page and this requires a Dispose function shown here: 
public void Dispose()
    {
        // Removed my app specific logic...
        changeOrderModificationSvc.Dispose();
    }

In the Dispose function of my service I simply set the values to what ever the "reset" version of the values are to be.

Comment: All - see my updated answer and a link to a recent article describing how to deal with the issue of getting services in an `OwningComponentBase` context from the Hub DI container.

Comment: Also if there is a follow on question, it's probably best to raise a new question referencing this question.